# React how to receive any event handler in props and add it to parent element

Tags: reactjs

With functional components, what is a good way to write a component that needs to be able to accept any event handlers and then apply it to the component's container element?

```
const Wrapper = (props) => {
    return <div ADD_ANY_EVENT_HANDLERS_FROM_PROPS></div>
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just pass an event. Functions are objects in JavaScript so props can be objects or primitive types or arrays or even a function.

Comment: @SanishJoseph But the Wrapper component doesn't know which events or how many will be passed into props.

Comment: <Component {...props} />; spread your props.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? If a prop is a concern of *some* parent component then pass the prop to the parent component, not the child component to try and pass back out somehow. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what your code is doing?

Answer (score 1):

@SanishJoseph answer seems correct. Thanks.

```
const Wrapper = ({message}, ...rest) => {
    return <div {...rest}>{message}</div>
}
```

This allows for any combo of event handlers to be passed in without knowing ahead of time what they will be. But any other leftover `rest` props will also be added so if they shouldn't be added they can be destructured.

```
<Wrapper 
    message="test1"
    onClick={(e) => console.log("clicked")}
    onMouseEnter={(e) => console.log("mouseenter")}
/>
```

Another Example:

```
<Wrapper 
    message="test2"
    onDoubleClick={(e) => console.log("double clicked")}
    onMouseLeave={(e) => console.log("mouseleave")}
/>
```